# getElementById does return null

Tags: javascript, html

I have following function in jquery:

```
$('canvas').createWindow('xyz', 500, 600);
```

And js-code behind is:

```
    var $ = function(element) {
        if (this.constructor !== $) {
                return new $(element);
        }

        alert(element);
        var windowObj = document.getElementById(element);

        this.createWindow = function(src, width, height) {          
            if(width != "" && height != "") {
                windowWidth = windowObj.style.width = width + 'px';
                windowHeight = windowObj.style.height = height + 'px';
            }
        };
    };
```

But the problem is that `js` says windowObj is `null`, but `alert(element)` works fine! Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an element of that `ID` in your HTML? Is `element` a string?

Comment: I guess then there is no element by that id in the document?

Comment: I've <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> in my HTML, element.toString() doesn't work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this on DOM ready or window onload? Do you have an element with an ID of `canvas`? You aren't confusing nodename with id?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>$('canvas').createWindow('xyz', 500, 600);</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ok.. you are calling it **before** it exists.

Comment: @pbcoder - please dont forget to select an answer if it has solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fine make sure that element is a id